# How to trigger callbacks when I modify an assocation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, associations

Imagine I have:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :bars
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :foos
  after_update :do_something
end
```

I'd like `@bar.foos << @foo` to trigger the `:do_something` callback. Is this possible? I'm on Rails 3.2.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer. There is a special set of callbacks that work on associations like this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 0):

If you mean can you trigger callbacks after an event on an active record object, yes. Check out [active record callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)